# When will Natty Narwhal 11.04 be stable to use?

Tags: 11.04

I have been wanting to try Natty Narwhal really bad. So about a week ago I tried it, and it was not at all stable. I know it's still in development but I desperately want Unity, I even reorganized my gnome panel with dockbarx and gnome window applets to try to emulate Unity. I tried Maverick early and it was great. :D (getting a little off topic here....) But anyways ;) When is Ubuntu Natty Narwhal 11.04 going to be ready for stable testing?

Answer (score 4):

You can use stable release in **April-2011**

Answer (score 2):

When it's released.

I don't mean to sound snide because I'm being serious. No pre-release version is recommended for production use. It may crash and break everything.

If you don't care about minor glitches, the beta releases and release candidates in late March through April should give a *fairly* robust experience.

Trying it at alpha stage is not recommended if you're not completely confident with all areas of an Ubuntu system.

Comment: It's the end of Aug 2011, and 11.04 STILL isn't stable. A USB 802.11n adapter caused my wife's box to crash 4 or 5 times a day. Seriously... when?

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu version numbers are the year and the month of any release, so 11.04 is 2011 April.  Anything before then is an unstable pre-release version and should only be used if you are okay with bugs and instability.

Closer to that date, there will be several beta releases followed by a few RC (release candidate) releases.  I've found that previous ubuntu versions are mostly good by the time the second beta comes out, which tends to be in the month or so before the official final release date. Even so, there may still be major bugs in the betas.

More about ubuntu's release process: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/ReleaseProcess